# Looking for an English-language poet whose name rhymes with Stowe and who lived in the time of Stevenson or earlier

Tags: poetry, identification-request

My friend is composing a poem, and for a rhyme's sake she needs the name of an English-language poet whose name rhymes with Stowe and who lived in the times of R.L. Stevenson or earlier.

I came up with "Poe" but she said she already used this surname. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Ideally it would be a poet whom Stevenson knew - not necessarily personally; a poet of whom he knew by reading his works will do.

I'm not sure if this question is on-topic; sorry if it's not.

Comment: I have the temptation to vote to close the question, because I'm against cluttering the SE. But that would be weird, so I'll abstain. And I'm not 100% sure the question is off-topic.

Comment: Asking "Which poets were contemporaries of R.L. Stevenson?" would have been acceptable I think. And might have found you some of @Tsundoku's answers. The rhyming stipulation then would just be weird but IMHO not a reason to close. Then again I tend to just want to be nicer to people in site betas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Robert Louis Stevenson lived from  1850 to 1894, so the following poets are candidates for the answer:

- [William Crowe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Crowe_%28poet%29) (1745–1829).
- [Richard Flecknoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Flecknoe) (c. 1600 – 1678).
- [J. Ingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Ingo) (lived c. 1800; only one poem, though).
- [John Bedford Leno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Bedford_Leno) (1826 – 1894).
- [Laurence Minot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurence_Minot_%28poet%29) (1300? – 1352?; contemporaries may have pronounced his name in a way that does not rhyme with Stowe).
- [William Roscoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Roscoe) (8 March 1753 – 30 June 1831), author of the poem for children [The Butterfly's Ball, and the Grasshopper's Feast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Butterfly's_Ball,_and_the_Grasshopper's_Feast).
- [William Caldwell Roscoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Caldwell_Roscoe) (1823–1859).
- [Nicholas Rowe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Rowe_%28writer%29) (/roʊ/; 1674 – 1718), well known for his edition of Shakepeare's works, but also a poet and dramatist in his own right.
- [Christopher Marlowe / "Kit" Marlowe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Marlowe) (1564 – 1593).

Comment: Names that end with an *unstressed* o don't really rhyme with Stowe, do they? The definition of thyme that I'm familiar with requires the rhyme to start with a stressed vowel.

Answer (score 3):

[Christopher Marlowe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Marlowe) would have been known through his work to Stevenson.  But it hardly scans.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Defoe (who wrote *Robinson Crusoe*) lived from 1660 to 1731, well before Stevenson. Further, Stevenson was a great admirer of his work. While Defoe is mostly known for his novels today, he also wrote poetry.